# React-router passing data to parent

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a simple React application using react-router to determine which page to display:

```
<Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route component={Navigation}>
        <IndexRoute component={HomePage}/>
        <Route path="/home" component={HomePage} />
        <Route path="/orders" component={OrderPage} />
        <Route path="/accounts" component={AccountPage} />
    </Route>
</Router>
```

Simple, and this works. What I would like to do though is have the navigation element include some data from the current page. Specifically the name of the page. So when on the order page the navigation element will display "Orders" and when on the accounts page it will include the text "Accounts"

But how does one pass this data in?

If it makes any difference I am using the material-ui (http://www.material-ui.com) library for UI components.